# Facebook targeted ad to target younger than 18

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

We have a free course which educates children between 14 and 16 how to learn and behave with disabled children  and how to best help them.

We plan to advertise it via Facebook targeted ads. But... We cannot create an ad to target younger than 18. But in reality all children from our aim group have Facebook accounts.

How shall we then advertise this course for our aim audience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing your ad set, the default range is 18-65. You should be able to change it.

[image: Facebook Ad Set]